# VBA, formatting strings in rows for Pivot Table Use

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am having trouble with formatting my cells.
I have a macro which populates file name , sheet name.

```
   Sub Headers
              'Headers and sheet names
Range("A1").Value = "File Name "
 Range("B1").Value = "Sheet Name "
 Range("C1").Value = "Node"
Range("D1").Value = "Scenario Name"

   Dim intRow As Long: intRow = 2

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
  If Sheets(i).Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
Cells(intRow, 2) = Sheets(i).Name
Cells(intRow, 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Name
intRow = intRow + 1
 End If
  Next i


    End Sub
```

I would like to know how I can repeat the sheet names to match with another column I have But have this work through a workbook no matter how many values I have for the given sheet.

For example , I have Sheetname1 in B2, Sheetname2 in B3, sheetname3 in B4,  in column C, I have values that need to line up with these.  For example: SheetName1 in B2 matches up with a value in C2. Sheetname2 in B3 matches up with a value in C3 and C4. So I would need to repeat Sheetname2 for B3 and B4 so it lines up. And this throws of my Sheetname3 and its value. I have many workbooks so this strategy would need to be dynamic.

The purpose of this is to make it easier to do a pivot table.  If it can be done without  me having to lineup these values perfectly let me know. Please any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How would the script know which sheet needs to match up with the data in column C?

Comment: @Bond not sure Bond, I mean if I can still pivot it without it being matched up, that will also work. The only way I can see it matching if the sheet name = values from the particular sheet